# How can I make a vertical symbol for a point which stands upright on the centroid?

Tags: symbology

Context: I need to display the location of wind turbines using a symbol from a True-type-font(ttf). The GIS software doesn´t allow me to define offsets, so I need to define a ttf which displays a turbine symbol which stands on the coordinate of the point. This is however more difficult than expected, because the font character is always centered on the point, however I design it. This means that the point location is always half way up the wind turbine and not at it´s foot.

Has anyone designed a ttf and found a solution to this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you are saying this problem is unrelated to your GIS software so it may be better researched/asked at [so] where the true-type-font tag has over 500 questions.

Answer (score 1):

What software are you using? Most of them have an option to define the offset for symbols. If the software you are using doesn't, then maybe you can edit the ttf symbol, like this:
http://youtu.be/_KX-e6sijGE

Comment: I was using font-forge...which also seems to be very buggy and crashes a lot.